# UPDATE with where clause based on subquery

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a table (CMS) that needs a column updated based on the columns in CMS and another table (CUST)... The row in CUST is referenced by a common column in CMS & CUST called CUSTNUM... I can not get this to work as intended, any help?

```
update CMS
set SHIPLIST = 'FEG'
from CMS
inner join CUST on CMS.CUSTNUM = CUST.CUSTNUM
```

Thank you.

Comment: *How* does this not work?  The SQL looks ok.

Comment: Can you explain what is not working in this query? What is your intended output for SHIPLIST?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your query looks fine.  There are other ways to express the query, such as:

```
update CMS
    set SHIPLIST = 'FEG'
    where CMS.CUSTNUM in (select Cust.CUSTNUM from Cust);
```

This can have better performance if there are multiple matches in the `Cust` table.  However, if your first version failed, then this might also fail.

Answer (score 0):

You can very well also use a correlated update query

Please refer to the post below :

https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/ssw_i5_54/sqlp/rbafyexsub4.htm

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about sql server. But this will work on MySQL

```
  update CMS
    inner join CUST on CMS.CUSTNUM = CUST.CUSTNUM
    set CMS.SHIPLIST = 'FEG'
```

The sequence should be **JOIN** first then **SET**

Answer (score 0):

You query looks fine...It worked when I did check in my test lab.

update CMS
set SHIPLIST = 'FEG'
from CMS
inner join CUST on CMS.CUSTNUM = CUST.CUSTNUM